# What is the source of the data for the ProgramFiles, ProgramW6432Dir, ProgramFilesDir (x86), CommonProgramFiles environment variables?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-7-x64

Where do the environment variables `ProgramFiles`, `ProgramW6432Dir`, `ProgramFilesDir (x86)`, `CommonProgramFiles` and `ProgramData` get their data from ?

Why is it impossible to change the values of these environment variables using `_putenv()` ?
For example:

```
_putenv( "ProgramFiles=D:\\MyProgs" );
```

Comment: `impossible to change the values` How do you check the return value of `_putenv` in order to assess whether the call failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 64-bit Windows system, the reading of the various environment variables and some Windows Registry keys is **[redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)** to different sources, depending whether the process doing the reading is 64-bit or 32-bit.

The table below lists these data sources:

```
X = HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
Y = HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
Z = HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
     
READING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:    Source for 64-bit process               Source for 32-bit process
-------------------------------|----------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------
                %ProgramFiles% :  X\ProgramW6432Dir                       X\ProgramFilesDir (x86)
           %ProgramFiles(x86)% :  X\ProgramFilesDir (x86)                 X\ProgramFilesDir (x86)
                %ProgramW6432% :  X\ProgramW6432Dir                       X\ProgramW6432Dir
     
          %CommonProgramFiles% :  X\CommonW6432Dir                        X\CommonFilesDir (x86)
     %CommonProgramFiles(x86)% :  X\CommonFilesDir (x86)                  X\CommonFilesDir (x86)
          %CommonProgramW6432% :  X\CommonW6432Dir                        X\CommonW6432Dir
     
                 %ProgramData% :  Z\ProgramData                           Z\ProgramData


      READING REGISTRY VALUES:    Source for 64-bit process               Source for 32-bit process
-------------------------------|----------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------
             X\ProgramFilesDir :  X\ProgramFilesDir                       Y\ProgramFilesDir
       X\ProgramFilesDir (x86) :  X\ProgramFilesDir (x86)                 Y\ProgramFilesDir (x86)
            X\ProgramFilesPath :  X\ProgramFilesPath = %ProgramFiles%     Y\ProgramFilesPath = %ProgramFiles(x86)%
             X\ProgramW6432Dir :  X\ProgramW6432Dir                       Y\ProgramW6432Dir
     
              X\CommonFilesDir :  X\CommonFilesDir                        Y\CommonFilesDir
        X\CommonFilesDir (x86) :  X\CommonFilesDir (x86)                  Y\CommonFilesDir (x86)
              X\CommonW6432Dir :  X\CommonW6432Dir                        Y\CommonW6432Dir
```

So for example, for a 32-bit process, the source of the data for the `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` environment variables is the Registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir (x86)`.

However, for a 64-bit process, the source of the data for the `%ProgramFiles%` environment variable is the Registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramW6432Dir` ...and the source of the data for the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` environment variable is the Registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir (x86)`

Most default Windows installations put a string like `C:\Program Files (x86)` into the Registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir (x86)` but this can be changed (and the others, too).

Below is the **typical** data in these environment variables and Registry values:

```
 READING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:   Typical data for 64-bit process         Typical data for 32-bit process
-------------------------------|----------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------                                                                        
                %ProgramFiles% = C:\Program Files                        C:\Program Files (x86)
           %ProgramFiles(x86)% = C:\Program Files (x86)                  C:\Program Files (x86) 
                %ProgramW6432% = C:\Program Files                        C:\Program Files

          %CommonProgramFiles% = C:\Program Files\Common Files           C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
     %CommonProgramFiles(x86)% = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
          %CommonProgramW6432% = C:\Program Files\Common Files           C:\Program Files\Common Files

                 %ProgramData% = C:\ProgramData                          C:\ProgramData
 
 
       READING REGISTRY VALUES:  Typical data for 64-bit process         Typical data for 32-bit process
 ------------------------------|----------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------
             X\ProgramFilesDir = C:\Program Files                        C:\Program Files (x86)
       X\ProgramFilesDir (x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)                  C:\Program Files (x86)
            X\ProgramFilesPath = %ProgramFiles% => C:\Program Files      %ProgramFiles(x86)% => C:\Program Files (x86)
             X\ProgramW6432Dir = C:\Program Files                        C:\Program Files

              X\CommonFilesDir = C:\Program Files\Common Files           C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
        X\CommonFilesDir (x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
              X\CommonW6432Dir = C:\Program Files\Common Files           C:\Program Files\Common Files
 
 X = HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

Ultimately, whatever is entered into these Windows Registry values will be read by Windows Explorer into respective Environment Variables upon login and then copied to any child process that it subsequently spawns. The child process can change its own environment variables using `_putenv()`

*The registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesPath` is especially noteworthy because most Windows installations put the string `%ProgramFiles%` into it, to be read by 64-bit processes. This string refers to the environment variable `%ProgramFiles%` which in turn, takes its data from the Registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramW6432Dir` ...unless some program changes the value of this environment variable apriori.*

I have written a small utility, which displays these environment variables for 64-bit and 32-bit processes.  You can download it [here](http://prototech.us/Registry.zip).
The source code for VisualStudio 2017 is included and the compiled 64-bit and 32-bit binary executables are in the directories `..\x64\Release` and `..\x86\Release`, respectively.

Comment: Windows Explorer is not the first process when you log in but it's parent exits quickly.

Comment: True, but does this process read these registry values into the environment variables ?